# How to license Craft for my customer?

Tags: license

As a web design shop we would like to license Craft not for ourselves but for our customers who run and own the future websites. How do we do that?

Answer (score 2):

Who "owns" a Craft license is very loosely defined as far as [Pixel & Tonic](https://pixelandtonic.com/) (the creators of [Craft](https://craftcms.com/)) is concerned.

A Craft purchase/edition is tied to the `craft/config/license.key` file that is in place at the time a purchase is made and wherever that file goes, the purchase/edition will follow.

In addition to that, a `license.key` file can only ever be tied to one public domain at a time.

As long as you give your client that `license.key` file and don't use it for other clients or projects, they "own" it.

How the license gets paid for is more up to you and your client.  i.e. either you purchase it and bill the client as a line-item on an invoice or have them purchase it directly.

Some relevant reading:

https://craftcms.com/support/license-key-info

https://craftcms.com/support/license-enforcement

Answer (score 0):

??? You either purchase the license on the client's behalf and bill the client for the cost or have the client purchase the license themselves. I'm  not sure what you're confused about. The license is attached to a domain.